# How to implement an autocomplete drop down like Google Chrome's?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to implement a custom drop down autocomplete suggestion list in HTML and CSS. I basically want it to look like Chrome's (see bellow.)

[image: Example of Chromes autocomplete drop down]

To implement this I tried using a table that is absolutely positioned bellow the input element. I then use `vertical-align: middle;` on the `td` elements and `text-align: right;` on the second `td` element only. Everything looks great as long as the table is left to automatically determine its own width. The issue is that when I set `min-width` on the table so that it is always at least as wide as the input. At that point there is blank space to the right of the second `td`. I've tried setting this second `td` to float right, or absolutely position it to the right, but nothing works. For starters, `vertical-align: middle;` seems to no longer work if I try either of those things. Secondly, with absolute positioning I get the two `td` elements overlapping at times.

Does anyone have a solution that would look/function like Chromes? Ideally I don't want to resort to dynamically changing styling with JavaScript. I also don't want to hard code element heights/widths because I want this to be flexible enough to be easily styleable.

Comment: You should use a library. This is fairly common.

Comment: @4castle I looked at the libraries that are available and they didn't suit my needs completely.

Comment: @4castle and in fact none of them function like Chrome's, so that is not much of a useful suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Chris, I can't seem to reproduce your problem. Min-width will extend the table and the rows/cols with it too.

```css
div {
  background-color: red;
}

table {
  min-width: 300px;
  background-color: green;
}

td {
  vertical-align: middle;
}

td ~ td {
  background-color: white;
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>first Col 1</td>
      <td>Second Col 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>first Col 2</td>
      <td>Second Col 2</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, it helped me find the issue. I should have included my CSS. For some reason I had the table element set to `display: block` which was causing this behavior.

Comment: OK, now I realize why I set it to display block... Now I can't set a max-height and use `overflow-y: scroll`.

Comment: use a div container and assign the max-height / overflow-y to it instead

Comment: One is glad to be of service!